# Proof of -(-v)=v in a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

The exercise is: *Prove that $-(-v)=v$ for every $v \in V$*

> *Proof*
>
> Suppose  $v \in V$ and $V$ is a vector space.
>
> Then $-(-v) \in V$ as result of the scalar multiplication property and
>
> $-(-v)=-(-1\cdot v)=-1 \cdot(-1\cdot v) =(-1 \cdot-1)\cdot v = 1 \cdot v = v $
>
> The desired result $-(-v)=v$ holds.

The solution manual gives the proof:

> *Proof*
> [image]

**I just wanted to make sure that the way I did the proof isn't missing anything?Thanks**

Comment: It looks like the solution manuals proof is answering a different question.

Comment: The screenshot you attached proofs other statement (?). Your proof is correct, but I think it's easier to derive it from definition of $-v$, since the opposite is unique.

Comment: @ Ben I'm sorry I took the wrong snapshot Ill correct it thanks

Comment: Perhaps $-v = (-1)v$ is not an axiom for "vector space", and if not then you cannot use it unless you prove it first.

Comment: Forget about the vector-space and just look at V as an abelian group. $-v$ is the additive inverse of $v$ by definition, so $(-v)+v=0$. This can be read the way that $v$ is the additive inverse of $(-v)$, thus $(-(-v))=v$. Similar thing here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1587024/290307

Comment: @GyroGearloose Thanks but I haven't taken abstract alg. yet but will definitely keep this in mind when I come across Abelian groups.

Comment: You see me in horror! How can your teachers expect you to proof anything without giving you axioms that you can use?

Comment: @GyroGearloose I'm self studying, but now I see what you mean by using the additive inverse axiom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is fine. Although this proof is a long winded version of the proof in the solutions manual, it is a little easier to grasp.

I like your proof, but to be pedantic, one would have to prove the commutativity of scalar multiplication with multiple scalars to a vector for your third equality. This is not presented in the book. So limiting ourselves to a subset of all the axioms and theorems until the point this problem shows up, I believe this is a not so elegant but straightforward proof.

Let $$ -v = w.\tag{1}\label{1}$$
Then we can write $-(-v)=-w$.
Since $-w$ is an additive inverse for $w$ we can write
$$w + (-w) = 0 .\tag{2}\label{2}$$We can also write $$v + (-v) = 0.\tag{3}\label{3}$$ from $\eqref{1}$ and $\eqref{3}$ it is clear that $$v+w=0.\tag{4}\label{4}$$ which means that $$v = -w.$$ Substituting in the value of $w=-v$ we get $$v=-(-v)$$ which concludes this proof.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems good, acknowledging the fact that V is a vector space, and therefore satisfies the axioms pertaining to the proof.